# Cannot read property 'someProperty' of undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on an application where I pass variable values in a Navlink using state from one component to the other and then load those received values in input fields and click on submit button in that other component to do something with values. My values are received correctly and show up correctly when I alert them. But when I click submit button, it gives error,pointing at the constructor

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Here is my code

```js
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={id:2}
    } 

    render(){
       return(
         <NavLink 
           to={{
             pathname: '/Child',
             state: {
               id: this.state.id
             }
           }}
         >
           Edit
         </NavLink>
       )
    )
}
```

Where I receive the values

```js
class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {id:this.props.location.state.id}
        alert(this.props.location.state.id)//works fine
    }

    setId(e){
        this.setState({id:e.target.value})
    }

    addOrEdit(){ //gives error    
        alert(this.state.id) 
        //do something    
    }

    render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <form>
              <label>Id</label>
              <input value={this.state.id} onChange={this.setId.bind(this)}  type="text"/><br/>
              <input type="submit" onClick={this.addOrEdit.bind(this)} ></input>
            </form>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `this.addOrEdit = this.addOrEdit.bind(this);` to your Child constructor

Comment: @Peter Coilingridge same error. nothing changes

Comment: Your onChange attribute should be `onChange={this.addOrEdit}` otherwise you are rebinding with a different `this`.

Comment: @PeterCollingridge: not true. `this` should be the component when running the `render` method.

Comment: In your question text you said the error is in the constructor, but your comment says it's in `addOrEdit`. Which line is it?

Comment: @Jacob You're right. It's still weird to bind it there. It doesn't look like the function is called.

Comment: @Jacob the error occurs when I click the submit button and addOrEdit function is bound to submit button but the webpage screen points towards constructor saying cannot read property id or undefined. The error doesn't otherwise occur in constructor initially. I can even do alert() and it works fine

Comment: I suspect that the error isn't in that function but the error is occurring on re-render which is calling the constructor. The error is most likely on the expression `this.props.location.state.id`; are you sure that `this.props.location.state` is always defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

```
 this.state = {id: this.props.location && this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.id}
```

---

Should fix your issue that caused by times that this component called without this context or this line got excuted before `location` set.
(assuming you using `withRouter` for making location props be exist...)

Anyhow, and not related directly to your issue, it is bad practice to set initial value for state from props at constructor, consider manipulate state through life cycle either don't use state here and refer to props directly

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to just use arrow functions for setId and addOrEdit.

```
addOrEdit = (e) => {
    // ...
}
```

And just call them:

```
onChange={this.setId}
onClick={this.addOrEdit}
```

https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb

Also you are deriving state from prop.
It is better to just use the prop directly.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html