# Redirect To Previous Page in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have a problem on redirect to the previous page since i do a check `isLoggedIn`. The problem right now is after check `isLoggedIn` it redirect to the default route. How do i maintain the page where I'm into?
What i did right now is using the `referer` but it is undefined. Pls help me find another way.
Pls check my code below:

**Login.js**

```
const Form = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
    const referer = props.referer;
    const history = useHistory();

    console.log(history);

    const { values, touched, errors, isSubmitting, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit } = props;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return <Redirect to={referer} />;
    }

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container direction="row" justify="center">
          <Grid item lg={4} md={5} xs={10}>
            <Card>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <CardHeader
                  title="LOGIN"
                  classes={{
                    title: classes.cardHeader,
                  }}
                  className={classes.cardHeader}
                />

                <CardContent className={classes.textFieldSection}>
                  <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    label="Username"
                    name="username"
                    type="text"
                    variant="outlined"
                    value={values.username}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    helperText={touched.username ? errors.username : ''}
                    error={touched.username && Boolean(errors.username)}
                    InputProps={{
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment>
                          <AccountCircle />
                        </InputAdornment>
                      ),
                    }}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    label="Password"
                    name="password"
                    style={{ marginTop: '1rem' }}
                    type="password"
                    variant="outlined"
                    value={values.password}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ''}
                    error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                    InputProps={{
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment>
                          <LockIcon />
                        </InputAdornment>
                      ),
                    }}
                  />
                </CardContent>

                <CardActions className={classes.loginButtonSection}>
                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    color="primary"
                    variant="contained"
                    className={classes.loginButton}
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                  >
                    Log In
                  </Button>
                </CardActions>

              </form>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  };

  let yup = require('yup');

  export const Login = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const MyFormWithFormik = withFormik({
      mapPropsToValues: ({ username, password }) => {
        return {
          username: username || '',
          password: password || '',
        };
      },
      validationSchema: yup.object().shape({
        username: yup.string().required('Enter your username'),
        password: yup.string().required('Enter your password'),
      }),
      handleSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        dispatch(login(values.username, values.password));
        setSubmitting(false);
      },
    })(Form);

    return <MyFormWithFormik />;
  };

  Form.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
  };

  export default Login;
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const authTokens = useSelector((state) => state.auth.access_token);

  function checkTokenExpiry() {
    if (authTokens) {
      axios.interceptors.request.use(
        function (config) {
          const token = `Bearer ${authTokens}`;
          config.headers.Authorization = token;
          console.log(config);
          return config;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }

  if (authTokens != null) {
    checkTokenExpiry();
  }

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        authTokens ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { referer: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**PrivateAdminOnlyRoute**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function PrivateAdminOnlyRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const authTokens = useSelector((state) => state.auth.access_token);
  const isAdmin = useSelector((state) => state.auth.is_admin);

  function checkTokenExpiry() {
    if (authTokens) {
      axios.interceptors.request.use(
        function (config) {
          const token = `Bearer ${authTokens}`;
          config.headers.Authorization = token;
          console.log(config);
          return config;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }

  if (authTokens != null) {
    checkTokenExpiry();
  }

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        authTokens && isAdmin === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : authTokens && (isAdmin === false || undefined || null) ? (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/pending', state: { referer: props.location } }} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { referer: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default PrivateAdminOnlyRoute;
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import Login from './pages/Login/Login';
import Signup from './pages/Signup/Signup';
import Common from './pages/Common';

function Routes() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Common} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default Routes;
```

Comment: have you tried `history.goBack();` ?

Comment: @HagaiHarari. Yes it has errors.

Comment: which errors? can you add this try and fail to your question?

Comment: @HagaiHarari. Sorry, there's no error but it redirects to login page

Comment: please add your `Router` declaration and the way you navigate into `Login` from the screen you want to go back to to your question

Comment: @HagaiHarari. Hi just added it. just tell me if its lacking or you add more recommendations/suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `state` inside `Redirect` isn't assigan `state` to `props` but to `location`

---

```
      import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';


      const location = useLocation();
      const referer = location.state && location.state.referer
```

---

another thing about your code (that not connect directly to your issue) is

```
(isAdmin === false || undefined || null)
```

`isAdmin` compared just to `false`, and in case `isAdmin` isn't `false` it is not being compared to `undefined`, but `undefined` stand by itself (with falsy behavior...), and so goes for `null`

hope it's helpful :)

Comment: I would do something like `authTokens && !isAdmin` what evaluate as `true` for all falsy values, and sorry mate I didn't  really follow your second question

Comment: on which path do you refresh?

Comment: I am not sure.. can you create a sandbox?

Comment: I think its because its checking isLoggedIn. I think we to have to add something in App.js? Like this in the pic https://ibb.co/VxV9p8v

Comment: about your first issue, maybe open a new question for it? is start to be to messy here..

about second issue -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61279604/cannot-read-property-someproperty-of-undefined-in-react/61279787#61279787, just adapt the code there that uses `this.props.location` to your usage of `location`

Comment: Ok. Can you edit your code on this part `this.props.location`. The referer undefined. Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Sorry but the error is the same `Cannot read property 'referer' of undefined`

Comment: Thanks. I'll just post another question for the other one. Thanks