# I want to go back to sign up page if token is null but I can't redirect it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

import { AppBar,Typography , Button , Toolbar} from '@material-ui/core';

import {Redirect, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';


const Admin = () =>{

    const history = useHistory();
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    let loggedin = true;
    if(token === null){
        loggedin = false
        if(loggedin === false){
            return history.push('/')
        }
    }
    


    const LogOut = () =>{
        
        localStorage.removeItem('name');
        localStorage.removeItem('password');
        history.push('/')
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography variant="h6">Admin Dashboard</Typography>
                    <Button color="secondary" variant = "contained" onClick={LogOut}>Logout</Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Admin;
```

Comment: if i manually write http://localhost:3000/admin i go to admin page without authorization. i dont want this.

Comment: I hope the following will solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62172263/redirect-to-previous-page-in-reactjs

Comment: Please [edit] your question- don't post updates as comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement authenticated routes in React Router 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164554/how-to-implement-authenticated-routes-in-react-router-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, It might help

```
  const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("token"));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token === null) {
      return history.push("/");
    }
  }, [token]);

  const LogOut = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("name");
    localStorage.removeItem("password");
    setToken(null);
  };
```